# Kill named running screen with -X only works after reattached

Tags: gnu-screen

I am using ubuntu 8.04.4 and would like to start daemons like this:

```
screen -dmS SESSIONNAME script.sh
```

Then i want to kill these screens with -X like so

```
screen -S SESSIONAME -X kill
```

But, this does not work. Only if i attach and detach that session it gets kill'ed with above command. What am i doing wrong? I would like to not have to attach/deattach the session to kill it since i want to use fabric scripts that start/stop daemons remotly.

-
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For daemons you really shouldn't be running them in screen.

In debian derived systems (such as Ubuntu) start-stop-daemon is the thing to use, RedHat and derivertives have a similar tool.

Read the man page, look at some init scripts for examples. on Ubuntu you may need to do a little delving as Upstart has mostly replaced standard init sctipts.

Comment: Yes you are right. 
These daemons are just for my development and the thing i want to use screen for is that i want to be able to start/stop them from my local system.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
screen -S SESSIONAME -X quit
```

Comment: Great, -X quit did the trick.

--
Thank you guys